# Using JSON_VALUE() when value contains unescaped double quotes

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, database, parsing

I have a table in the database where in one field (name of the field - JSONDetail) JSON is stored. Recently we encountered a problem where in this field in one of the values there are unescaped double quotes. It's due to migration from another system which allowed double quotes to be stored in the database without backslash before them.

Example (see field "comment"):

```
{
    "noteId": "a34f17c4-f4fd-45ea-b4da-732ef8126a6b",
    "memberName": "Test  LINKOUS",
    "tenantId": "548bead1-bdab-e811-bce7-0003ff21d46b",
    "noteType": "General Note",
    "memberId": "84cf0adb-850d-e711-80c8-000d3a103f46",    
    "createdOn": "2020-09-13T17:47:33.2864868Z",    
    "comment": "test "word" test",    
    "contacts": [
        {
            "otherContactType": "",
            "communicationType": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

We need to identify such cases in the database. I tried:

```
select JSON_VALUE (JSONDetail, '$.comment') as Comment
```

But instead of **test "word" test**, it returned

[image]

How can I return what is actually stored in key "comment"?

Comment: Is it one column only where this happens or could it occur in any of the others as well?

Comment: Only in one column

Answer (score 0):

SQL-server does not have "fix_json" function

To find junk records

```sql
select *
from table
where ISJSON(json_col) = 0
```

Fix founded records via back-end language (php, c#, etc)

To prevent such behavior in future add constraint

```sql
ALTER TABLE table
    ADD CONSTRAINT [record should be formatted as JSON]
                   CHECK (ISJSON(json_col)=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT] It wasn't practical to infer the field location in the JSON string based on length.  Based on CHARINDEX search for the field names, this code finds and fixes the 'comments' in the JSON.

Data

```
drop table if exists #json_to_fix;
go
create table #json_to_fix(
  json_col          nvarchar(max));

declare @json            nvarchar(max)=N'
{
    "noteId": "a34f17c4-f4fd-45ea-b4da-732ef8126a6b",
    "memberName": "Test  LINKOUS",
    "tenantId": "548bead1-bdab-e811-bce7-0003ff21d46b",
    "noteType": "General Note",
    "memberId": "84cf0adb-850d-e711-80c8-000d3a103f46",    
    "createdOn": "2020-09-13T17:47:33.2864868Z",    
    "comment": "test "word" test",    
    "contacts": [
        {
            "otherContactType": "",
            "communicationType": ""
        }
    ]
}';
insert #json_to_fix(json_col) values (@json);
```

Query

```
select s.not_escaped, fix.string_to_fix,
       replace(fix.string_to_fix, '"', '') fixed
from #json_to_fix j
     cross apply
     (select charindex('"comment":', j.json_col, 1) strt_ndx) c_start
     cross apply
     (select charindex('"contacts"', j.json_col, c_start.strt_ndx) end_ndx) c_end
     cross apply
     (select substring(json_col, c_start.strt_ndx, c_end.end_ndx-c_start.strt_ndx-11) not_escaped) s
     cross apply
     (select substring(s.not_escaped, 13, len(s.not_escaped)-13) string_to_fix) fix
```

Output

```
not_escaped                     string_to_fix       fixed
"comment": "test "word" test"   test "word" test    test word test
```

Answer (score 0):

If `comment` keys are followed by `contacts` key throught the table within the JSONDetail column, then you can use the following code block which contains `SUBSTRING()`, `PATINDEX()`, `TRIM()` and `LEN()` functions to extract the whole value of the `comment` key in order to compare with the value extracted from `JSON_VALUE (JSONDetail, '$.comment')` :

```
WITH t(json_extracted,str) AS
(
SELECT JSON_VALUE (JSONDetail, '$.comment'), 
       SUBSTRING(  
                 JSONDetail,
                 PATINDEX('%"comment"%', JSONDetail),
                 PATINDEX('%"contacts"%', JSONDetail)-PATINDEX('%"comment"%', JSONDetail)
                 ) 
  FROM tab
), t2(json_extracted,str) AS
(
SELECT json_extracted,
       TRIM(
            SUBSTRING( str, PATINDEX('%:%', str) + 1, 
                            PATINDEX('%,%', str) - PATINDEX('%:%', str) - 1 ) )
  FROM t
)
SELECT SUBSTRING(str,2,LEN(str)-2) AS extracted_comment,
       CASE WHEN json_extracted = SUBSTRING(str,2,LEN(str)-2) 
            THEN
                 'No'
            ELSE
                 'Yes'
            END AS "is_it_corrupted"
  FROM t2
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=dd4d8fc061efd0cc574d6d6220fee496)</kbd>